# test sqlite upgrade script after updating windows phone 8 silverlight to 8.1 runtime

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

i updated my application from WP 8.0 silverlight to 8.1 runtime. On each new version there is an update script to the sqlite.
Before the update to 8.1, I used to test the upgrade script by using visualstudio to deploy the old version first the deploy the new version the was no problem as they have the same manifest file.
Now when i do that i end up with two applications with the same.

my question: how can deploy the new app on the old app? what is the right values for the manifest? or what else can i do?